# How to use gojs implements similar cacti network weathermap？

Tags: openweathermap, gojs

how to use gojs implements  similar  network weathermap
cacti weathermap 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOog5.png)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this: https://gojs.net/temp/twoStrokeLinkCurved.html

[image]

The link template is fairly normal, except that the main path (the first Shape) isn't drawn at all, there is a non-visible link label whose size causes duplicate links to be routed farther apart from each other than normal, and there is a custom link label that draws the two opposing arrowheads at the middle.

```
myDiagram.linkTemplate =
  $(CurvedTwoPartLink,
    { curve: go.Link.Bezier, relinkableFrom: true, relinkableTo: true },
    $(go.Shape, { stroke: null, fill: null }),
    $(go.Shape, { stroke: null, fill: null, width: 35, height: 15 }),
    $(go.Shape,
      { // the double-arrow in the middle of the link
        geometryString: "F1 M0 0 L6 3.5 12 0 M0 7 L6 3.5 12 7",
        fill: "white", segmentOrientation: go.Link.OrientAlong
      }),
    $(go.Panel, "Auto",
      { segmentIndex: 0, segmentFraction: 0.75 },
      $(go.Shape, { fill: "white" }),
      $(go.TextBlock, { margin: 2 },
        new go.Binding("text", "text1"))
    ),
    $(go.Panel, "Auto",
      { segmentIndex: -1, segmentFraction: 0.75 },
      $(go.Shape, { fill: "white" }),
      $(go.TextBlock, { margin: 2 },
        new go.Binding("text", "text2"))
    )
  );
```

The crux of the implementation is that there are actually two additional Links for each apparent Link.  Those two links are styled in the way that you want, whereas the main path Shape can only be stroked with a single color.  Those two Links connect to an additional label Node that is on the main Link.  Look at the implementation in the sample to see how it works.